# Stack Driver logging with SLF4J not logging properly in scala

Tags: scala, google-cloud-platform, slf4j, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I am using Logback with SLF4J for Stackdriver logging and I am following the example from [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java). My application is written in Scala and running on Dataproc cluster on GCP.

`logback.xml` have the following contents.

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="CLOUD" class="com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender">
    <!-- Optional : filter logs at or above a level -->
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
      <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
    <log>application.log</log> <!-- Optional : default java.log -->
    <resourceType>gae_app</resourceType> <!-- Optional : default: auto-detected, fallback: global -->
    <enhancer>com.company.customer.utils.MyLoggingEnhancer</enhancer> <!-- Optional -->
    <flushLevel>WARN</flushLevel> <!-- Optional : default ERROR -->
  </appender>

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="CLOUD" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

and MyLoggingEnhancer is

```
package com.company.customer.utils

import com.google.cloud.logging.LogEntry.Builder
import com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingEnhancer

class MyLoggingEnhancer extends LoggingEnhancer {

  override def enhanceLogEntry(builder: Builder): Unit = {
    builder
      .addLabel("test-label-1", "test-value-1") //also not showing on the stack driver
  }
}
```

And I am constructing logging object in classes

```
 private val LOGGER: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
```

And I logged a message from logger object like

```
LOGGER.info("Spark Streaming Started for MyApplication")
```

The issue is `resourceType` and `logName` is not properly set on Stackdriver logs. `logName` is automatically set to **yarn-userlogs** and `resourceType` is set to **cloud_dataproc_cluster**. I want to set **resourceType = Global** and **logName = MyApp** so that I can filter MyApp logs under Global hierarchy.

I tried with after removing this line from `logback.xml`.

```
<resourceType>gae_app</resourceType>
```

and by adding this line

```
<resourceType>global</resourceType>
```

but no luck. Any kind of Help highly appreciated. The label **test-label-1** which i provide is in LoggingEnhancer is not showing on Stackdriver as well.

My Json Payload on Stackdriver is

```
{
insertId: "gn8clokwpjqptwo5h"
jsonPayload: {
    application: "application_1568634817510_0189"
    class: "com.MyClass"
    container: "container_e01_1568634817510_0189_01_000001"
    container_logname: "stderr"
    filename: "application_1568634817510_0189.container_e01_1568634817510_0189_01_000001.stderr"
    message: "Spark Streaming Started for MyApplication"
}
labels: {
    compute.googleapis.com / resource_id: "1437319101399877659"
    compute.googleapis.com / resource_name: "e-spark-w-2"
    compute.googleapis.com / zone: "us"
}
logName: "projects/myProject/logs/yarn-userlogs"
receiveTimestamp: "2019-10-01T05:25:16.044579001Z"
resource: {
    labels: {
        cluster_name: "shuttle-spark"
        cluster_uuid: "d1557db6-72ee-4873-a276-4bd4ea0e89bb"
        project_id: "MyProjectId"
        region: "us"
    }
    type: "cloud_dataproc_cluster"
}
severity: "INFO"
timestamp: "2019-10-01T05:25:10Z"
}
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @VikasVats not yet through slf4j. Currently i am logging via `com.google.cloud.logging.Logging`. I am getting logger object in this way.
`logger: Logging = LoggingOptions.getDefaultInstance.getService`

Comment: My issue is with LoggingEnhancer. I am not able to see fields added in stackdriver.

Comment: my issue was the same.

Comment: Thanks. With this way, I think I would have to write log entries code to each class? I want a common configuration to add metadata to all application logs. Do you have any idea?